# Is the Mathieu Groupoid $M_{13}$ even special, besides its construction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, groupoids

The Mathieu groupoid [$M_{13}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_groupoid) has a beautiful construction from a "sliding block puzzle" produced from the projective plane of order $3$; put $12$ labelled counters on $12$ of the $13$ points of the projective plane, and look at all the configurations one can reach by moving a counter on a line with the empty spot onto the empty spot, and swapping the other two counters on that line. This gives a groupoid (like a group, but two moves can only be composed if they are compatible as to where the empty spot is). The marvelous things is that look at all permutations of the $12$ counters the occur with the empty spot in a common place (which now form a group), you get the sporadic group $M_{12}$. For those not familiar with $M_{12}$, note it and $M_{24}$ are the only finite groups that are $5$ transitive (besides the obvious symmetric and alternating groups), though there's a lot more that can be said about their exceptionality!

My questions is as follows: while this construction is excellent, is the structure of $M_{13}$ itself any more interesting than $M_{12}$? If we just see it as a groupoid, the answer seems to be no; [any two connected groupoids on the same number of objects with same fundamental group are isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120657/is-a-connected-groupoid-uniquely-determined-by-its-objects-and-fundamental-group), so such an object existing is not a surprise.

However, this groupoid also comes with a group action by the symmetries of the projective plane, and maybe the groupoid equipped with this action is more of a "surprising" or exceptional fact? It makes me ask the question: for any group $G$ acting on a set $S$, and group $K$, is there always a connected groupoid with objects $S$, automorphism group of any object being $K$, and an action by $G$ that when restricted two the groupoids objects, is the action on $S$? And is it unique? That is, are connected groupoids with a group action classified by more than a the group action and the automorphism group of objects? And if so, is there some clear way in which $M_{13}$ is particularly special, besides involving a sporadic group?

Possibly there is some structure even beyond that of the group action we want to imagine $M_{13}$ having, that demonstrates its exceptionality. I'd appreciate any perspectives on $M_{13}$ that clarify any of these questions, even if they aren't exactly what I have in mind. Even if it turns out only the construction is exceptional (in some sense) and not the resulting object, I'd still be happy enough!

Comment: Your link text to that question, " any two connected groupoids on the same number of objects are isomorphic", does not quite capture the content of that question! (For example, the claim in the link is clearly false)

Comment: Ah yes, of course I also mean for same automorphisms of objects, let me fix that